# exporting UV texture

Tags: texturing, uv

I am new to blender, I made a rocket model with a texture and it looks fine in blender[image: in blender]

however when I export it and put it into a game engine the texture is not right
[image: in game engine]

any tips on how I can correct this?

[image]

Comment: Do you have more than one UV map on the mesh?

Comment: what do u mean? I am using one texture, but all the components of the texture are seperate

Comment: I used a smart UV project

Comment: You can have multiple UV maps on one mesh. Also the texture looks different color, are you sure you are using the same file? Can you add your blend file to see whats wrong? http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: the yellow is on the bottom of the rocket, for some reason it is smearing over the side too. I do not know how to attatch a blend file

Comment: [<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=282" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/282/)

Comment: The texture is not packed in the blend file, but I dont see any reason in the UV to show a result like that. You have some unnecessary overlapping faces and Unwrapping could be done better. Which format did you use for export the model?

Comment: I used a .obj file, yes I was just testing with this model and did not put much time into stuff like that

Comment: sorry, I forgot to do that, this one is packed I believe [<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=283" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/283/)

Comment: I got it to work using a different way of obj loading....but my previous obj loader still doesnt work, I may be making a mistake with exporting because the old one works with all my other models...